# addEventListner not working on factory function object

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, factory

I create a factory function to return a button object, on consol.log I got the the right result but on applying addEventListner it's not working

```
          const tabButton = function(name)
        {
            const button = document.createElement("button")             
            button.innerText = name
            button.classList.add("btn")
            return {button}
        }
        
        const displayWebsite = function()
        {
            const btn = tabButton("name").button
            console.log(btn)                          //<button class="btn">name</button>
            btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                console.log("debug")                  // not working
            })
        }
```

Comment: Did you append the new button to some DOM's node?

Comment: Where do you append the button to the DOM and click it?

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```js
function tabButton(name) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");             
    button.innerText = name;
    button.classList.add("btn");
    document.getElementById("theButtons").appendChild(button);
    return button;
}
        
function displayWebsite() {
    const btn = tabButton("name");
    console.log(btn);
    btn.addEventListener("click",() => {
        console.log("debug")
    })
}

displayWebsite()
```

```html
<div id="theButtons"></div>
```

Comment: Please accept this answer (click on the checkmark) if this answered your question. If you have any more doubts, feel free to comment :).